# R mosaicplot package vcd greyscale for publication

Tags: r, plot, grayscale

Hello I would like to know how to produce greyscale mosaicplot with VCD package

For instance

```
mosaic(~ Sex + Survived, data = Titanic,
       main = "Survival on the Titanic", shade = TRUE, legend = TRUE)
```

Produce blue and red mosaicplot.

I tried

```
mosaic(~ Sex + Survived, data = Titanic,
       main = "Survival on the Titanic", shade = TRUE, legend = TRUE, highlighting_fill = grey.colors)
```

But it does not work.

How to get a greyscale mosaicplot.

Answer (score 1):

If the chroma `c` is switched off (= set to zero) in `shading_hcl()` then all colors are collapsed to the corresponding grayscale colors. The result will be essentially what @S12000 suggested but in any device, not just PDF.

Additionally one can change the line type of the mosaic tiles to code the sign of the residuals. Then large positive and large negative residuals can be distinguished. Of course, not as easily as through different hues but in principle it is possible.

Using the `Titanic` example, you can use either full color:

```
mosaic(~ Class + Survived, data = Titanic, legend = legend_fixed,
  gp = shading_hcl)
```

[image: mosaic-color]

Or the corresponding grayscale values with different line types:

```
mosaic(~ Class + Survived, data = Titanic, legend = legend_fixed,
  gp = shading_hcl(Titanic, c = 0, lty = 1:2))
```

[image: mosaic-gray]

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I just saved it with pdf R function with the param `colormodel="gray"`

```
pdf("D:/save.pdf", colormodel="gray")
mosaic(~ Sex + Survived, data = Titanic,
       main = "Survival on the Titanic", shade = TRUE, legend = TRUE)
dev.off()
```